# Web page generator like LaTeX

Tags: latex, markup

forgive if this is dumb. I was wondering if there was any such thing like LaTeX, by which you could write in a markup and compile it to a whole web page (of course with CSS and other styling). I've heard of lightweight markup languages like Textile. But I don't think they serve my purpose.

Comment: Then what *is* your purpose?  Why is textile not sufficient?

Comment: See even if you use textile you'll have to worry about styling, or use some CMS. What I want is something which creates styled static webpages

Comment: do you want to take html with css and produce html without css, with all css effects coded into page?

Answer (score 1):

Try [HyperText Markup Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML)

Comment: "write in a markup and compile it to a whole web page" - HTML does the job pretty well in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

If you really enjoy inflicting pain upon yourself, you could use m4.